# On windows 7 admin can't change environment variables and virtual memory,etc

Tags: windows-7, windows, administrator, environment-variables

Yesterday I want to set up a web server on my computer.After installing some software(probably MySQL cause the problem,I think),there is an odd problem with my Windows 7.
I'm an admin user,but now I can't change some advanced system settings,for example,environment variables and vitural memory,the buttons are gray.What's more,when I open devices manager,a window pops up and say that I can only view,but can't make any changes because I'm a standard user.However,if I search device manager in start menu,right click and run it as admin,I can make changes.The same thing apply to other admin tools like msconfig and gpedit.msc.Also,in the past,when I run some installer,there will be UAC prompt to run it as admin,but now there isn't,and if I just run it by double click,it will run as non-admin and the installtion fails.I have to right click and run it as admin.
I have a guess about the problem:when you run some things,such as administrative tools,windows run them as admin by default(if you are an admin user).But now,the installtion of some software mess up some system settings so windows doesn't run them as admin by default,and cause my problem above.
I tried to create another admin user,and everything is normal when I log in as that user,no such problem.Unfortunately,I have to use my old user,for some reason.
Please help me deal with the problem.Thanks.
**UPDATE:** I managed to gain access to environment variables and vitural memory settings by killing exlorer.exe process and re-running it as admin.But then everything I run automatically has admin privilege,and I don't want that to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Try UAC settings Change to Notify me only when programs try to make changes to my computer.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sorry,my but my UAC setting is already at this level.I tried to change it to the lowest level,but the problem still exists.

Comment: Have you tried to create a new user could be problem with the current user environment.

Comment: No,I can create new admin users,and as said above,new users don't have the problem.I do have admin privilege,but the problem is administrative tools isn't automatically run as admin.For example,I can right click and run msconfig and gpedit.msc as admin,no problem.But if I run them by left click,it denied access and say I'm a standard user.

Comment: However,advanced system settings like network ID and environment variable,they are in explorer.exe,there is no way to right click and run as admin.

Comment: 1. Create other admin account login into it
 2. Remove the faulty one without deleting files
 3. Rename AdminFolder in c:\users\
 4. Recreate the first admin
 5. Move old files to new user created directory OR take ownership and delete the created folder and rename it back to orginal ... This should fix it

Comment: By the way,some softwares wasn't installed for all users....And I can't see them in the new admin user.Will I be able to use them without reinstalling them in the recreated user?

Comment: yes its located in c:\users\(YOUR ADMIN USER ACCOUNT)\Start Menu\Programs or run (echo %UserProfile%\Start Menu\Programs) in cmd its just created shortcut from the installation path

Comment: It's a good tip, but didn't work (UAC level already set).  This used to work, I've updated the path many times before.  I want to know how the account got fubar or at least how to fix it without creating a new account (my account is a domain account with local Admin privileges)

Comment: Another interesting note:  I can delete items from the Path, but not add new strings... anyone seen that?  Very strange.

Answer (score 16):

I was able to fix this by selecting a specific search result from the Start Menu.

Instructions:

1. Click Start button
2. Type "path"
3. Select "Edit the system environment variables" (most likely the second Start menu search result)
4. Click "Environment Variables..." button
5. That's it!

If you choose "Edit environment variables for your account" from the Start menu search results instead, you will only be able to edit environment variables *for your account*.

Comment: Seriously, that is so confusing. I figured it out seconds before I read your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are two places to change environment variables, under Contraol Panel.

User Accounts: let's you change your own environment, and override system settings.

System | Advanced: Has a button "environment variables" that lets you change both yours and the system settings.